# How do I make a graph of pseudo frequency vs. time. in ssqueezepy?

Tags: eeg, array-signal-processing

How do I make the y axis in psuedo-frequency?

```
Wx, scales = ssqueezepy.cwt(sig, wavelet = 'morlet', scales='log-piecewise', nv = 32, t = time_vector)

ssqueezepy.imshow(Wx, abs = 1, borders = False)
```